# Google Api PHP Client - How to login

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to connect using the api of google using php to loggearme with the user of gmail and retrieve the calendars I have, for this I use this code.
What I get is loggearme and that oauth2 I return the *TOKEN* but once I have this token I do not know how to use it to get the details of my google calendar.

Thank you

**Settings.php**

```
/* Google App Client Id */
define('CLIENT_ID', 'XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com');

/* Google App Client Secret */
 define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'XXXXXXX');

 /* Google App Redirect Url */
 define('CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL', 
 'http://localhost:8081/googleTesting/oauth2callback.php');


    <html>
<head>....</head>

<body>



 <a href="<?= 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=' . urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile') . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL) . '&response_type=code&client_id=' . CLIENT_ID . '&access_type=online' ?>">Login with Google</a>
<br>

   </body>
 </html>
```

**Calendar.php**

```
//  We have access we can now create our service
if (isset($_SESSION['datosGoogle']['access_token'])) {

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['datosGoogle']['access_token']);
print "LogOut";

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();;

while(true) {
    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {

        echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary()."\n";


        // get events
        $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id);


        foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
            echo "-----".$event->getSummary()."";
        }
    }
    $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request a login to google you add scope in that request.

Google has better answer. [Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth),[Google php implementation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php)

This part is important to highlight.

```
//import libraries php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
```

Comment: Thxs , this is that I need.